# ESX host cmd to check if physical host went to battery

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Trying to trouble shoot some issues on a server and see if it's related to loss of power, they have cheap APC that don't have logging or interface.  I've checked the event log in v-sphere but don't see any events related to power loss.  Wondering if there a command in the esx-cli or v-sphere to determines if the host server went from AC power to APC ?

Comment: What do you mean by PSU? I am no native english speaker, but in my understanding PSU is the power supply - the part where the power cable goes into your server. Normally servers do not have batteries (lets ignore the CMOS batteries to keep the time while power is disconnected). I thing what you want to know is if the UPS (uninterruptible power supply) switched to battery?

Comment: @Tobias APC people call them PSU's sorry for confusion, many OS's can sense when the power goes from AC to DC

Comment: Well... they're called UPS's: Uninterruptable Power Supply. A PSU is a Power Supply Unit. And a PDU is a Power Distribution Unit.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna I never heard hat VMWare could sense by its own that the UPS went to battery. There are esxi plugins for some UPS vendors, if this is the case than you could be lucky. But esxi out of the box - not as far as I know of. 
You are saying that you APC UPS has no way of telling if there was a power outage and it was running on battery? No log of any kind?

Comment: You need an UPS agent/plugin on the ESXi, or one in a guest, connecting to host management. ESXi by itself doesn't talk to a UPS.